# How do I remove a UIImageView drawn at some specific point on my UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uikit

Every time I want to draw an image ("goodCell.png" in this case..), at some specific x-y coordinate on my View Controller's window, I call the following method, including the appropriate parameters :

```
-(void)paintGoodCellatX:(int)xAxis andY:(int)yAxis onViewController:(UIViewController*)playingViewController
{
    int x = 32*(xAxis - 1);
    int y = 384 - (32* yAxis);

    UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goodCell.png"];
    UIImageView* myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y, 32, 32);
    [playingViewController.view addSubview:myImageView];

}
```

If at some later point during my code I want to delete one of the above images the were drawn at some specific x & y coordinate, how do I do that?

Given this code I have nothing to hold on to an ImageView I drew (therefore I can't use something like `[myImageView removeFromSuperView];` since the name `myImageView` defines nothing), except for its coordinates. So is there a way to delete/remove a UIImageView at specific x-y coordinates on a View Controller window or some other way to work around this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: You want to draw some thing on UIImage.So for undoing, have you checked NSUndoManager https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a TAG to your views to give you a meaningful identifier.  Use myImageView.tag = XXX;

Then use [playingViewController viewWithTag:XXX] to get the UIImageView handle of the view you want to remove.

The tag is an integer, it could be the offset into an NSArray where you store these X/Y locations, or a key into an NSDictionary where you store these values?

Comment: So even though `myImageView` object will constantly change and define some new place on the ViewController's window (every time the method is called), `myImageView.tag = ...` will still be "pointing" at the same place if I add that to an Array that exists outside this method, right?

Comment: tag is just a numeric identifier.  It must be unique across your views.  It is "attached" to the view.  You can then retrieve a view from the hierarchy via this tag value via viewWithTag.  So you'll need an NSDictionary or some other model object to allow you to map your X/Y coordinates to this tag #.

Comment: No, with a "tag", you track the object, not the position on screen. So if you define a view with tag 1 at position A and move it to position B, then add another view with tag 2 on same position A and delete the view with tag 1, the view at position B will be removed.

Comment: @lukaswelte idea about encoding the X/Y coordinates as XXXYYY is a novel idea, same concept but no need for an NSDictionary...

Comment: (side note) CSmith, you posted your comment while I was writing mine, obviously the "No" of the beginning of my comment is not for yours :)

Comment: And I agree with CSmith, you should create an NSMutableArray, and insert a X/Y coordinates at the index of the corresponding tag. For example, if you add a view with tag 4 at position (10,25), put a custom "coordinate" object (you'd have to create an NSObject subclass) like "(10,25)" at index 4 of your array. When you move a view, update its coordinates in your array. When you want to delete a view by its coordinates, search for its tag in the array.

Comment: great, thank you once again! I'll go on and try this and I'll come back to you if something goes horribly wrong! :)

Comment: trouble with NSMutableArray and using the array index [as your tag] is when you go to remove a view (and its corresponding array element), it will shift your indexes and cause you grief.  Using a keyed Dictionary will avoid this

Answer (score 1):

You could give every view a tag that is calculated by the point so for example 3 digits x than 3 digits y axis as tag

for x=312 y=567 it would be

```
myImageView.tag = 312567;
```

with this you could always identify the view

Another and the better possibility would be to store all the added in an NSArray.
If you want to remove one specific view, you would have to iterate through the array and check wether the point is in the bounds of the view
So more or less:

for creation;

```
NSMutableArray *imageViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
-(void)paintGoodCellatX:(int)xAxis andY:(int)yAxis onViewController:(UIViewController*)playingViewController
{
    int x = 32*(xAxis - 1);
    int y = 384 - (32* yAxis);

    UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goodCell.png"];
    UIImageView* myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y, 32, 32);
    [playingViewController.view addSubview:myImageView];
    [imageViewArray add:myImageView];
}
```

for deletion:

```
for(UIImageView *mv in imageViewArray) {
 if(CGRectContainsPoint(mv.bounds, yourCGPoint)) 
  [mv removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Yes as CSmith already suggested using tags and storing those values in an NSArray of a global scope is the best way I guess. Thanks to both of you. If only I could accept 2 answers! :)

Comment: If you make a tag "naming convention" like I suggested you don't need to store anything in an array… The array is a second solution that doesn't need tags and can also remove multiple views that contain this point

Comment: I think what Luka P. was looking for is a way to delete the view at a position, so if 2 views are created with your tags like 111222 and 333444, and then you invert them, view with tag 111222 will be at position (333, 444), so if you want to delete this view by removing view with tag 333444, you'll remove the wrong one ! (whoa, that's hard to explain, lol)

Comment: Thats why I proposed a second solution that stores the image views in an array and then really checks if the actual position of the image view includes the point where he wants to delete the imageview.. with this second solution he can move and transform the view just like he wants to without regarding that the tag would need to change

Comment: ok I'm a bit lost myself now but I will post the solution I ended up choosing/understanding once I have it ready. By the way, I won't be moving views around. Just deleting and creating views at specific points if that makes any sense or difference. Anyway, I'll post when it's ready :)

Comment: I updated my answer and added a little more detail in the explanation of the "better"/Array storing solution